# Providing response to client using HttpSession

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

I am creating a Chat Server kind of application using AsyncServlets and JSPs. Suppose there are two clients A and B. When A types some chat, it should be seen on client B's page. I have recorded the HttpSessions for both A and B when they first login into the Application. Can somebody tell me how to send A's chat response to client B if we have B's HttpSession id ?

We are not bound to use HttpSession if we can solve the problem otherwise using any other technique.

Comment: I'm no sure you can "send A's chat response".  It is all about requests and responses.  Most likely, client B would have to periodically request any new "chat responses" from other clients.

Comment: no, client B does not request. this is the prime condition. server should feel the need to send when to update the client B.

Comment: How are your clients communicating with the server?

Comment: Have you tried websockets? Googling "java websocket chat" gives a lot of results.

Comment: by simple "get" or "post" requests. When they press "enter" or press a button, the chat goes to server.

Comment: sp00m....I have not used websockets...but have idea about normal socket programming....can u help on that matter?

Comment: As @sp00m indicates, you'll have to use some sort of asynchronous communications channel like WebSockets, Server-Sent Events or Long Polling to get the notification / data to the other client. Of course you could always poll periodically but that creates all kinds of scale problems. Take a look at Atmosphere (https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) which provides a solution that abstracts away some of the complexities of building this type of application.

Comment: Out of these, which one would be the most efficient one?

Comment: Check java.nio package. You will have something to implement Comet application. That is reverse Ajax.